# How to add an if statement inside a Puppet class creation

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a *Puppet* manifest which creates a class, with another class inside it:

```
class profiles::common::wlsdomains {
    class {"wlsdomain":
            applications      => hiera('wlsapplications', ""),
            crontab           => hiera_hash('crontab', ""),
            generateWlsdomain => hiera('generatewlsdomain'), # This line needs changing
    }
}
```

So far so good. Now, the problem is the last line. I only want to set `"generateWlsdomain"` to `"hiera('generatewlsdomain')"` *under certain conditions*. This is where the need for an `"if"` statement comes in. I'd like to replace that line with something like this:

```
if $::generate == "true" {
    generatewlsdomain => "true"
}
elsif $::generate == "false" {
    # Do nothing; leave generatewlsdomain unset
}
else { # If $::generate is neither "true" nor "false", then get a value from Hiera
    generateWlsdomain => hiera('generatewlsdomain'),
}
```

In other words, I want to primarily look at $::generate to decide what to do, but use a value from Hiera as backup if $::generate isn't set.

However, something tells me I can't just replace the existing line with this code block, because the existing line is part of a comma-separated *list*, it's not just a generic code line of its own.

In case it matters, this is running on a *RedHat* machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `undef` keyword can be used as the value if you don't want to set it, which will cause Puppet to use the default value for `generateWlsdomain`.

Using this, set a variable for the value of `generateWlsdomain`:

```
if $::generate == "true" {
    $generatewlsdomain = "true"
}
elsif $::generate == "false" {
    $generatewlsdomain = undef # Do nothing; leave generatewlsdomain unset
}
else { # If $::generate is neither "true" nor "false", then get a value from Hiera
    $generatewlsdomain = hiera('generatewlsdomain')
}
```

or a bit more compact, using [a selector](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_conditional.html#selectors) to test `$::generate` values and set `$generatewlsdomain` with the result:

```
$generatewlsdomain = $::generate ? {
  "true"  => "true",
  "false" => undef, # Do nothing; leave generatewlsdomain unset
  default => hiera('generatewlsdomain'), # If neither "true" nor "false", then get a value from Hiera
}
```

and pass it into the existing class declaration:

```
class {"wlsdomain":
  applications      => hiera('wlsapplications', ""),
  crontab           => hiera_hash('crontab', ""),
  generateWlsdomain => $generatewlsdomain,
}
```